# Python method (static method) which iterates through several methods based on the list of tags & gives output one at a time

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, static-methods

I am trying to take the output of a python method. But the output is not straight forward. The current python method have some tags & values where it iterates through the tags & corresponding functions & get the value as output. I would like to take the output as a list or DataFrame. But output is coming one at a time & it creates new list or new dataframe every time the method runs through the current method. 
I am new to python & not so skilled at advanced data handling in python. 
Please help me to get the desired output.

I need all the output compiled as a single list or dataframe for all tag values.

The sample code is given below

```
 @wrapper
 def Output(self, refid: int, db: str, tag: str, value: str, remarks: str):
    super().Outupt(refid, db, tag, value, remarks)

    # Tried this below option, but i couldn't get the output as list
    # l = enumerate([tag, value])

    # I tried to convert it as dataframe. But there also the output is one at a time. 
    d = pd.DataFrame([tag, value])
```

The outuput is a DataFrame as stated below

The tag has been assigned to a python method where there are 23 tags there in the list. all 23 outputs will come one by one when we execute this above function.

Current Output:

[image]

Desired Output:
[image]
Please help me to decode this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is not a static method... in any case, I'm having a tough time understanding what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Hi, Sorry i missed the first line
@wrapper 
the above line supposed to be there before the code. 

What i need is, the above method will take a tag value & run the corresponding python function & get the output. Likewise it will do for 25 tags & output the values. Whenever the values are out, it is coming one at a time. and i need to put everything in one dataframe. Please help me out here.

Comment: Yes, it's still not clear at all. You really need to provide *more details* as to *exactly* what you require. There shouldn't be any ambiguity. I don't know what you mean "the output is one at a time".  I also have no idea what you mean by `@wrapper`.

Comment: Hi, I have added the current output & the one i would like to have. Could you please check & guide me?

Comment: Hi, any help here on this request...

Answer (score 0):

```py
# I'm starting with an assumption that you have lists of tags and values.
# However, if you need to build the lists from your method calls, e.g. 
# mylist = list()
# mylist.append(myfunc())
# the code below is for 10 tags but scale as needed
# there are many ways to accomplish...below, I used the zip fcn to bind the tags value pairs 
# a dataframe is a nice container if you have many sets of values per tag (i.e. spreadsheet like)
# think of list objects like cols in a spreadsheet. zip them together to create a df.
# notice how the initial df is in long format (most common scenario for dataframes)
# finally, I transposed the df giving the desired output.
# hopefully enough to get you on the path

import pandas as pd
```

```py
tag = [F"Tag{i}" for i in range(1, 11)] #python indexing starts with zero by default...changed for esthetics
values = ['OLD', 100, 100, 0, 0, 0,'VWbug',0,0,'NEW']
```

```py
tag
```

```
['Tag1',
 'Tag2',
 'Tag3',
 'Tag4',
 'Tag5',
 'Tag6',
 'Tag7',
 'Tag8',
 'Tag9',
 'Tag10']
```

```py
d = list(zip(tag, values))
d
```

```
[('Tag1', 'OLD'),
 ('Tag2', 100),
 ('Tag3', 100),
 ('Tag4', 0),
 ('Tag5', 0),
 ('Tag6', 0),
 ('Tag7', 'VWbug'),
 ('Tag8', 0),
 ('Tag9', 0),
 ('Tag10', 'NEW')]
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Tag', 'Value']) 
df = df.set_index('Tag') #set index to column of choice
df
```

```py
    Value
Tag 
Tag1    OLD
Tag2    100
Tag3    100
Tag4    0
Tag5    0
Tag6    0
Tag7    VWbug
Tag8    0
Tag9    0
Tag10   NEW
```

```py
df.transpose() #row index used to name cols
```

```py
Tag     Tag1    Tag2    Tag3    Tag4    Tag5    Tag6    Tag7    Tag8    Tag9    Tag10
Value   OLD     100     100      0      0       0       VWbug    0      0       NEW
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
But my requirement is, taking the values from an output of the above python method. 
Since the method gives output only 1 at a time, the above solution is not working.